# How to check and uncheck parent and child inputs with jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my blogs module i can assign categories to each blog.Categories may have child categories as shown in this code:

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach(App\Http\Controllers\CategoriepageController::getAllPage() as $page)
        <tr class="parent">                 
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="page_id[]" 
                    value="{{ $page->id }}" 
                    {{ App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::existPageLiaison($page->id, $article->id) == 'true' ? 'checked' : '' }} 
                    class="parent"
                >
                { $page->title }}
            </td>
        </tr>

       @foreach(App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController::getCategoriesPage($page->id) as $categ)
            <tr class="child">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $categ->id }}" 
                        name="idCateg[]" 
                        style="margin-left: 40px;" 
                        {{ App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::existCategLiaison($categ->id, $article->id) == 'true' ? 'checked' : '' }}
                    >
                        {{ $categ->title_fr }}
                </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach()
    @endforeach()
</table>
```

for unchecking children when parent is unchecked i tried this:

```
 $('.parent').on('click', ':checkbox', function() {

        if ($(this).not(':checked')) {

          var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');

          console.log(currentRow);

          var targetedRow = currentRow.nextAll('.child').nextUntil('.parent');

            console.log(targetedRow);

          targetedRow.each(function(index,element){

            var targetedCheckbox = $(element).find(':checkbox');

            targetedCheckbox.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');

          })

        }

      });
```

but it doesn't work properly for all inputs(all child inputs are unchecked except for the first one).

I am using a script to check parent input if one of it's children is checked.What is missing in my script is if  all child inputs are unchecked i want the parent input to be unchecked and second when i uncheck the parent input i want all child inputs to be unchecked.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there might be easier methods, but I believe this will help. Do input the Laravel blade codes such as foreach and ids.

Example: 
`<input type="checkbox" name="page_id[]" value="1" id="parent_1" onchange="parentChanged(1)"> My Title 1`

change to

`<input type="checkbox" name="page_id[]" value="{{ $page->id }}" id="parent_{{ $page->id }}" onchange="parentChanged({{ $page->id }})"> {{ $page->title }}`

```js
function parentChanged(parent_id) {
  if ($('#parent_'+parent_id).prop("checked")) {
    $('.child_'+parent_id).prop("checked", true);
  }
  else {
    $('.child_'+parent_id).prop("checked", false);
  }
}

function childChanged(parent_id) {
  if ($(".child_" + parent_id +":checked").length > 0)
  {
      $('#parent_'+parent_id).prop("checked", true);
  }
  else
  {
     $('#parent_'+parent_id).prop("checked", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="page_id[]" value="1" id="parent_1" onchange="parentChanged(1)"> My Title 1
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idCateg[]" class="child_1" onchange="childChanged(1)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idCateg[]" class="child_1" onchange="childChanged(1)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="idCateg[]" class="child_1" onchange="childChanged(1)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="idCateg[]" class="child_1" onchange="childChanged(1)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="idCateg[]" class="child_1" onchange="childChanged(1)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="page_id[]" value="1" id="parent_2" onchange="parentChanged(2)"> My Title 2
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idCateg[]" class="child_2" onchange="childChanged(2)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idCateg[]" class="child_2" onchange="childChanged(2)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="idCateg[]" class="child_2" onchange="childChanged(2)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="idCateg[]" class="child_2" onchange="childChanged(2)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="idCateg[]" class="child_2" onchange="childChanged(2)"> My Category
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: perfect i just changed the first function to this function parentChanged(parent_id) {$('.child_'+parent_id).prop("checked", false);}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check if there is at least one children checked or none.

If none then uncheck the parent input, otherwise check the parent input:

```
$( 'input[name="idCateg[]"]' ).on( 'click', function() {
    // Check if there are children checked
    var has_child = false;
    $( this ).closest( '.child' ).children( 'input' ).each( function() {
        if( this.value == true ) {
            has_child = true;
        }
    } );

    // set the parent checkbox after check the children
    if( has_child == true ) {
        $( this ).closest( '.child' ).prevAll( 'tr.parent:first' ).find( 'input' ).val( true );
    } else {
        $( this ).closest( '.child' ).prevAll( 'tr.parent:first' ).find( 'input' ).val( false );
    }
} );
```

Comment: all actions that i need are on the client side (jquery)  not with laravel

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya i've updated my answer, check it out